# how can i create a custom <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to enlarge the arrow of the select tag and set its background to green.
The width of the box must be 100px and the height 50px. I tried a lot of css but it didn't worked out

[image]

```css
.select_box{
    width: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1 solid #000;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12;
    padding: 10 15;  
    margin-left: 10;
    margin-top: 5;
}
.select_box:after{
    width: 10; 
    height: 50; 
    border-left: 6 solid transparent;
    border-right: 6 solid transparent;
    border-top: 6 solid white;
 
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    right: 5;
    content: "";
    z-index: 98;
    background-color: green;
    background-size: auto;
}
.select_box select{
    width: 110;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select_box">
  <select>
    <option > Position</option>
    <option > Height</option>
    <option > Width</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: there are a ton of questions about this. Please search before posting here. Possible duplicate of [CSS Select box arrow style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668404/css-select-box-arrow-style) or other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```css
.select-style {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  heigh: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent
    url("https://i.imgur.com/qJolQ2D.png") no-repeat
    93% 50%;
}
.select-style select {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  width: 150%;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.select-style select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.select-style:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #77d800;
  top: 0;
  right: -1px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-style">
  <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

> Sorce: [How to put background-color only a section of a select? CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984575/how-to-put-background-color-only-a-section-of-a-select-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use after, before for select, but you can use background like this:
https://codepen.io/Lincox/pen/mQRpPm

```css
/*Remove style of select*/
select{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.custom-select{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/arrow-keys-png-image-7.png) right 10px center/10px 10px no-repeat;
  background-color: green;
}

.custom-select2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(https://static.thenounproject.com/png/4350-200.png) right 10px center/20px 20px no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="custom-select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select class="custom-select2">
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Accept and let me know if it works